# Printing cells with text only NOT formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have created a workbook that uses formula to populate lists, one of which uses VBA to print labels.

My problem is the VBA sees the cell formula in blank cells and wants to print blank tags. How can I change it to see text only?

As I said, I need to edit my VBA to ignore formula and read only the resulting text.

### VBA is below.

---

```
Sub Print_Labels()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Col_Width_1 = Range("Column_Width_1")
    Col_Width_2 = Range("Column_Width_2")
    Col_Width_3 = Range("Column_Width_3")
    Col_Width_4 = Range("Column_Width_4")

    Row_Height_1 = Range("Row_Height_1")
    Row_Height_2 = Range("Row_Height_2")
    Row_Height_3 = Range("Row_Height_3")
    Row_Height_4 = Range("Row_Height_4")

    Sheets("Equipment_List").Select
    Num_Equip = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Start_Row = Range("Title_Label_Start_Row")
    First_Page_YN = True

    Names.Add "Equipment_List", "=" + Range("A1").Resize(Num_Equip).Address

    Sheets("Labels").Select
    ' Set page setup


    ' Set column widths
    For Count_Label_Columns = 1 To Num_Label_Columns
        Range("A1").Offset(, (Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 
    4).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Col_Width_1
        Range("B1").Offset(, (Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 
    4).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Col_Width_2
        Range("C1").Offset(, (Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 
    4).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Col_Width_3
        Range("D1").Offset(, (Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 
    4).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Col_Width_4
    Next Count_Label_Columns

    ' Set row heights
    For Count_Label_Rows = 1 To Num_Label_Rows
        Range("A1").Offset((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4).EntireRow.RowHeight = 
    Row_Height_1
        Range("A2").Offset((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4).EntireRow.RowHeight = 
    Row_Height_2
        Range("A3").Offset((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4).EntireRow.RowHeight = 
    Row_Height_3
        Range("A4").Offset((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4).EntireRow.RowHeight = 
    Row_Height_4
    Next Count_Label_Rows

    ' Work out the first label row to be printed
    If Start_Row > 10 Then Start_Row = 10
    Count_Label_Rows = Start_Row

    ' Labels always start printing in the first column
    Count_Label_Columns = 0

    For Count_Equip = 1 To Num_Equip

        ' Start of new page of labels, so completely clear sheet
        If First_Page_YN = True Then
            Cells.Clear
            First_Page_YN = False
        End If

        Count_Label_Columns = Count_Label_Columns + 1
        If Count_Label_Columns > Num_Label_Columns Then
            Count_Label_Columns = 1
            Count_Label_Rows = Count_Label_Rows + 1
        End If
        If Count_Label_Rows > Num_Label_Rows Then
            Count_Label_Rows = 1
            Count_Label_Columns = 0
        End If

        If Count_Label_Rows = 1 And Count_Label_Columns = 0 Then
            ' Start of new page, so print full sheet
            If Range("Title_Print_Preview") = "Print" Then
                ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            Else
                ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
            End If
            Cells.Clear
            Count_Label_Columns = 1
        End If

        Range("Title_Label_Format").Copy
        Range("Labels_Top").Offset(((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4), 
      ((Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 4) + 1).PasteSpecial
        Range("Labels_Top").Offset(((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4) + 2, 
      ((Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 4) + 2) = _
            Range("Equipment_List").Offset(Count_Equip - 1).Resize(1, 1)
        ' Enter the sequence number of the equipment
        Range("Labels_Top").Offset(((Count_Label_Rows - 1) * 4), 
    ((Count_Label_Columns - 1) * 4) + 3) = Count_Equip
    Next Count_Equip

    ' Print or Preview the last sheet
    If Range("Title_Print_Preview") = "Print" Then
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Else
        ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In your question, it sounds like the example you provided is a scenario in which the the blank cell is the result of the formula, and the macro reads the formula result into the tags. Please post the code you are using. What types of labels and tags are being referenced?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Post some sample data to illustrate what you want to achieve and post code and formulas you use. Then explain in context what you expect to happen and what happens instead. Read [ask], then edit your question and after that post a comment to alert the followers of this question.

Comment: `Range.Text` property

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is a command which starts preparing a new label for printing. You need a check at that point which tell the program to skip that entry if the source data are incomplete. If you have access to that code you might show it here and someone will point to the spot to change and perhaps suggest a modification.